# textTransform is not valid in react-native drawer options?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I want the text in my drawer options to be uppercase.  So I did the following code.

```
const drawerOptions = {
    drawerPosition:'right',
    drawerBackgroundColor:'#86959a',
    contentOptions:{
        activeTintColor:'white',
        inactiveTintColor:'white',
        labelStyle:{textTransform:'uppercase'}
    },
};

const Navigator = DrawerNavigator(Router,drawerOptions);
```

However, I get a warning

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `textTransform` supplied to `Text`.

How do I get my menu items in the drawer menu to be uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're using the [`drawerLabel` option](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer) to pass in the text you want?  So you could manually set the text to uppercase like this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  drawerLabel: 'MENU ITEM'
};
```

If you're passing in a variable rather than a manually entered string, you could use JavaScript's `toUpperCase()` function:

```
const menuItem = 'menu item';
static navigationOptions = {
  drawerLabel: menuItem.toUpperCase()
};
```

Comment: oh, so there's no such thing as text transform uppercase in react native?

Comment: There's not actually, no - have a look here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1243

React Native doesn't have support for all CSS properties, but we can use JS to compensate.  React, meanwhile, supports regular CSS and stylesheets akin to regular web development.